# How does a web browser know if destination is http or https?

Tags: browser

I use Wireshark to analyze web traffic.

When i open my web browser and type in the address: stackexchange.com, it first performs a DNS query, receives an answer, and then sends a TCP Syn packet to proper IP address at port 80.

But when i type in www.paypal.com, it does the same but TCP Syn packet is sent directly to port 443.

The DNS answer doesn't seem to include destination port, neither is there any protocol negotiation between my browser and target site. **How does my browser know destination port?**

Note that i don't type in http://stackexchange.com or https://www.paypal.com, but simply stackexchange.com and www.paypal.com.

Comment: It almost seems like paypal.com is a "special case"?! _Normally_, if you typed in `www.example.com`, the browser would request "http" on port 80. It would then be up to the website to redirect you to https (port 443), or reject the request altogether. However, with paypal, even with all caches clear, there is no redirection to "https" as far as I can see? The browser appears to cancel/change the typed request, so the very first request is for "https"! This would be a good security feature if this is indeed what is happening? Tested in Chrome Inspector.

Comment: Interestingly I see the "http" to "https" redirect for `www.paypal.com` in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome or Opera. To me this looks like it is perhaps a special "feature" of these browsers?

Comment: @w3dk Perhaps they're using HSTS https://scotthelme.co.uk/hsts-the-missing-link-in-tls/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your browser remembers the port and protocol from previous interaction with the site.

Paypal uses HTTP Strict Transport Security.  This means that the server had sent (perhaps via port 80) a response header including `Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=63072000` before you even started looking.  The age shown is in seconds.  So for the next two years after a visit to port 80 the browser does not have to go to port 80 again; it should go to port 443.  In fact subsequent visits to port 443 will receive the same instruction, so it applies indefinitely for people who use Paypal every year.

This is an improvement over the previous scheme where each request to port 80 got a redirect to port 443 which was slower.  Relying on redirects was also less secure because the browser would not mind if Paypal (or rather a MITM attacker impersonating Paypal) suddenly converted from HTTPS to HTTP, if using redirects.  Under HTTP Strict Transport Security, this kind of attack will end up much more conspicuous as the attacker would be forced to use HTTPS to talk to the browser, but they do not have access to any HTTPS server certificate issued to Paypal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Given that, as far as I remember, the last time I visited Paypal was about the day I initially asked the question, the automatic redirection should have expired. However, I just retried the experiment and again the request to port 443 was immediate. Can I do something to verify that your answer is correct (perhaps track that saved header down and erase it from the history of my browser)? I'm using Firefox 49.0.2 for Windows 7 if this is relevant.

Comment: @Adayah - I used Chrome to do research for my answer.  Feel free to do the same.  Tools - More Tools - Developer Tools - Network - pick a request - Headers.

Comment: @Adayah One of the guys who invented HSTS is from Paypal.  I bet that they use it for a long time - even pre-standard.  Nobody knows what was the effective max-age value given by the Paypal site x years ago.  You might be able to decode this from your browser's records if you cared enough.  Also, any visit to the whole paypal site will count, even an ad on an unrelated page would.

Comment: Got it! I clicked "Forget About This Site" via the right-click context menu of the history item www.paypal.com and then retried the experiment (visited www.paypal.com without http:// or https:// prefix, with Wireshark listening). The first request was to HTTP. It looks you are right.

Comment: But what about the first connection?

Comment: In the case of Paypal specifically, they use https://hstspreload.org/. Your browser comes with a list of URLs that should always be HTTP**S** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816785/which-hsts-preload-list-is-used-by-which-browser

Answer (score 0):

The browser usually tries HTTP first, then gets a redirect to HTTPS. That's the common case, but not the only one.

Chrome and Firefox support the notion of [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) Preload Lists which are lists of sites which should only be contacted via HTTPS, even if referenced with a HTTP URL.

More detailed info can be found [here](https://www.copahost.com/blog/http-vs-https/).

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer/Microsoft Edge address this limitation by implementing a "HSTS preloaded list", which is a list that contains known sites supporting HSTS.
So, the request from your browser goes to the respective HSTS configured server domain directly on https.

Otherwise, there had to be a http request and the server would have had to redirect to https (in case of HSTS, the server responds with header - use only HTTPS: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000).

Answer (score -1):

The webrowser will always ask for the port 80, so after all the ssl service its server side, when a client connect to yours service the server redirects the connexion to a secure one or "https".

Comment: The web browser won't always ask for port 80. You can configure it to always request 443 or physically type https:// at the start of the address. You can also have plugins which force https requests.

Comment: By default and in the first instance it is, of course you can change it as you want, but the process is that.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure the point was made. Came across as though you always had to make this default request regardless of the setup.

Comment: No, that musn't be the case. In the second example, the very first packet sent after receiving DNS response is a TCP Syn packet with destination port 443. If port 80 was default, it would be captured by Wireshark and displayed before any server-side redirection could happen.

Comment: One of the possibly process is that, but every site can have a different configuration.