# How does the Browser know that HTTPS is wanted?

Tags: tls

Say I request a website (example.com). Via DNS, an IP is returned and the request is sent there. Does the browser always first try port 443 (HTTPS), given an IP address? TLS is started from the client side, so does the browser send Client Hello first to IP-<Port 443> and see if a reply comes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a web browser know if destination is http or https?](https://superuser.com/questions/799464/how-does-a-web-browser-know-if-destination-is-http-or-https)

Answer (score 3):

1. If the link starts with https:// instead of http://
2. If the domain is in HSTS Preload List
3. If the domain sent HSTS header in previous visit with this browser and it has not yet expired
4. If the browser is in "HTTPS-Only Mode" (Firefox)
5. If something like the "HTTPS everywhere" extension is used

Comment: also, many webservers are configured to either automatically redirect or to rewrite the url to HTTPS.

Comment: If you're being attacked with a man in the middle attack, the legitimate origin server redirecting to https doesn't help you. The first request needs to be performed with https. Non preloaded HSTS helps only in case you're safe at home but are being attacked by some guest wifi somewhere.