# How does the browser know that the website is using HTTPS for a TLS handshake to start?

Tags: browser, webserver

After an established TCP connection, if the website uses HTTPS, the client and server perform a TLS handshake, but how does the browser know that the website is using HTTPS in the first place for a TLS handshake to start?

[image]

Comment: https is the default brotendo https://blog.chromium.org/2021/03/a-safer-default-for-navigation-https.html

Comment: also https://superuser.com/questions/799464/how-does-a-web-browser-know-if-destination-is-http-or-https?rq=1

Comment: The browser knows because the URL starts with `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: zAlso, I think ypur diagram is overly simplistic and ignores SNI (The browser and server establishing the domain name prior to tls megotiation). It also makes assumptions about the version of https - eg ignores https over udp variants.